# Find objects through multiple conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For a quiz application, I am trying to display ACTIVE questions, in which the current user has not answered. The answer table has a user_id and question_id that I'm trying to use. I thought I was close with the following query (in the static_pages_controller.rb:

```
@questions = Question.active_question.where.not(id: @user.answers)
```

It seems to not work in all situations when I am testing it though. I feel like I'm close, but not sure where to go from here. Pretty new to Rails so greatly appreciate any assistance!

question.rb

```
 has_many :answers

  scope :active_questions, -> { where("? BETWEEN start AND end", Time.now.to_date)}
  scope :activeAtDate, lambda{ |date = Date.today| where("? BETWEEN start AND end", date) }
```

answer.rb

```
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user

  scope :user_answered, lambda {|q| where("question_id == (?)", q) }

  validates_uniqueness_of :question_id, scope: :user_id
```

user.rb

```
 has_many :answers
```

static_pages_controller.rb

```
 def index
    @user = current_user

    if user_signed_in?  
      if @user.manager_id != nil
        @manager = @user.manager_id
      end
      @my_team = User.where("manager_id = ? AND id != ?", @manager, @user.id)
      @questions = Question.active_question.where.not(id: @user.answers)

    end

    @new_answer = Answer.new


  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pretty new to Rails

Welcome - you've done very well so far.

I originally thought you should be calling the questions from your `@user.answers` association - then I realized you wanted questions to which the user had not answered.

...so I'd do the following:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def non_participating_questions
     answered_questions = self.answers.pluck(:question_id)
     Question.active_questions.where.not(id: answered_questions)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
@questions = @user.non_participating_questions
```

The benefits of attaching this to the `User` model is that you can use the `instance_method` (so you don't have to pass `@user` each time). It also means you're able to deal with all the associative data a `user` has as well (`answers` etc).

Comment: That worked perfectly!! I was always pretty close to getting it but something would throw it off. This is the implementation I was looking for exactly. Thanks again for your help.